# Trimming file extension using CMD or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have the following 2 files in a directory which I would like to change:

`a.exe.deploy` ⇒ `a.exe`
`b.config.deploy` ⇒ `b.config`

I saw use cases of `ren` for this, but I can't get it to trim the last part.

Answer (score 5):

Rename the file(s) to their basename. Example:

```
Get-Item 'C:\path\to\a.exe.deploy' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the use of Substring() with Lastindexof()

Example:

```
$s = "a.exe.deploy"
$s.Substring(0, $s.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to use `ren` for this task:

```
ren *.*.deploy *.
```